# Get class name minus namespace without using Reflection

Tags: php, class, oop, reflection, php-7

Is there a simple way to get the class name without the namespace **without** using Reflection?

This is my class and when I call `get_class()` I get `CRMPiccoBundle\Services\RFC\Webhook\SiteCancelled`

```
namespace CRMPiccoBundle\Services\RFC\Webhook;

class SiteCancelled extends Base implements Interface
{
    public function process() {
       // echo get_class()
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a special reason you don't want Reflection? Besides that, if you have the class name as string you can use PHP's string functions on it.

Comment: Create class property with class name and use it))))

Comment: replace ____NAMESPACE____   in getclass?

Comment: Find the last occurrence of ``\`` and take everything after it… http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php

Comment: I see the comments and answers using `str_replace` but I full expected PHP to offer a cleaner way of doing that rather than having to rely on string manipulation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Or simply exploding the return from `class_name` and getting the last element:

```
 $class_parts = explode('\\', get_class());
 echo end($class_parts);
```

Or simply removing the namespace from the output of `get_class`:

```
echo str_replace(__NAMESPACE__ . '\\', '', get_class());
```

Either works with or without namespace.

And so on.

Comment: Cannot use `end` without declaring a variable. Is there an alternative to get the last element?

Answer (score 7):

Use the `class_basename()` function to get your class name without the namespace

```
<?php

echo class_basename(__CLASS__);
```

Comment: The class_basename() function does not exists.

Comment: `class_basename` is a [function from Laravel](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php#L69), not from PHP itself.

Comment: well, I'm using Laravel, and I was looking for this. Grazie @LucaMurante :-)

Answer (score 2):

So many ways to do it using string manipulation…

If you're certain your class name contains a namespace:

```
$c = 'CRMPiccoBundle\Services\RFC\Webhook';

echo ltrim(strrchr($c, '\\'), '\\');
echo substr($c, strrpos($c, '\\') + 1);
```

If you're uncertain whether the class may or may not contain a namespace:

```
echo ltrim(substr($c, strrpos($c, '\\')), '\\');

preg_match('/[^\\\\]+$/', $c, $m)
echo $m[0];
```

And probably many other variations on that theme…

Answer (score -1):

This is the fastest method I've came up with and seems to be working for all cases:

```
function toUqcn(string $fqcn) {
   return substr($fqcn, (strrpos($fqcn, '\\') ?: -1) + 1);
}
```